# FOSUserBundle - Unique session access

Tags: php, security, symfony, fosuserbundle

Using Symfony 2.0 and FOSUserBundle, I need to know how to restrict the access to make it unique.

This is what I mean:

1. User X accesses to my system creating a session through login/password
2. With that session still valid (not having closed the session, etc...), the same user X tries to access from a different computer or location.
3. In that case, I need the system to avoid its second access with some kind of message: "that user has a valid session from another computer".

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible and **trustable** only if you could find a secure way to know when the user session has destroyed or he has logged out from the other computer. As it can occurs without explicit action from the user (i.e. he closed the browser and the session timed out), I wouldn't rely on it. Of course you could always try to find some workaround (i.e. predicate session expiration time and track user logging out) but it still would not be 100% secure. Thinks about cases where new accesses will be denied because a session is still open on another browser without people in front of it.

On the other hand, you can do it the other way (when new user logs in, the other logs out) using [Voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html) and some hints found in [Allow one session only at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3164543/1337344).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I'll get that second option. What do you think about this: use the last_login datetime. FOSUserBundle saves automatically that data in the database. When the user logs in, save that complete datetime (seconds accurate) in the session. When any request is made, check that the information coincides in both places (session and user table). Otherway, say bye bye and destroy the session. Good approach, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think there is finally no way to do what I am trying to since Chrome (and I think FF too) save the exact cookie and are able to restore the session skiping all LoginHandler methods.

Let me explain myself.

Right, I was about (and actually I did) to implement the solution described in your answers and comments:

1. User X enters the web site with his login/password using Safari (for example)
2. The login datetime is stored both in table `User` in the database and in session
3. Without logging out, the same User X opens a different browser (Chrome, for example)
4. The new login datetime is updated in database and in Firefox session
5. The user gets back to Safari and tries to refresh the page
6. He gets an exception as the datetime doesn't coincide with the one stored in session

Well... great so far, as it seems to solve the problem.

And here comes the big deal: as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies) and [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-bugs/cjt3WwgOJ3c), Chrome is not deleting properly the session cookies. So when user doesn't logs out and just close the browser, anytime he or she comes back to Chrome, the session is automatically restored without passing through a login handler, login method or anything around.

This causes that "magical" datetime key not to be saved both in database and session and, as a result, put a stick in the wheel of letting just one session as a time, what was the original plan.

Any more light on the issue??

I want to cry :(

Comment: As I said you should also implement your own [Voter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html) that will take care of these datetime comparisons. Whenever comparison fails (5-6 in your example), you log out the user (see ["Symfony2: how to log user out manually in controller?"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6474975/1337344)) and `return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;`. See the documentation for more information on security and how to implement a custom voter.

Comment: Thanks, I understood it well. But, please, read from the point where I begin "And here comes the big deal". Really, I understand how to make that comparisons (even without Voter framework (although I'll take a look at it)), but the problem is, as I said, that I will never be able to intercept the session creation as it is not created indeed, but just recovered and not passing through any "LoginHandler" or Login method or anything like that. May be I am really missing something, but I don't get it. I'll take a look to Voter, but according to what you said, I don't think it will solve.