# How to force user logout symfony2

Tags: php, wordpress, security, symfony, logout

I want to force a user to logout in symfony2 after checking that it has not enough capabilities for access into a specific secured area.

I've tried with :

```
$this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();
```

but it seems that something goes wrong, the user still logged in until I logged him out using /logout route.

I've to mention that I'm using KayueWordpressBundle to connect my symfony app with a wordpress based website to create a custom back office.

Here is my security.yml file

```
security:
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    login_firewall:
        pattern:    ^/$
        anonymous:  ~
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        kayue_wordpress: ~
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

providers:
    wordpress:
        entity: { class: Kayue\WordpressBundle\Entity\User, property: username }

encoders:
    Kayue\WordpressBundle\Entity\User:
        id: kayue_wordpress.security.encoder.phpass
```

How can I do this please ?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2: how to log user out manually in controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464754/symfony2-how-to-log-user-out-manually-in-controller)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can force logout by calling `setToken()` with `null`, try something like this:

```php
$this->container->get('security.context')->setToken(null);
```

It will destroy user token from the security context and kick the user out.

---

Also, please see this question for more details: [Symfony2: how to log user out manually in controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464754/symfony2-how-to-log-user-out-manually-in-controller)

Comment: above given solution will not call logout handler, if i have registered any handler for logout.

Comment: BTW, use `$this->container->get('security.authorization_checker')` instead (new in 2.6)

Comment: @Ronan, it's `$this->container->get('security.token_storage')`. See [New in Symfony 2.6: Security component improvements](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements).