# How to prevent blocked user from logging in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a user table with user info including a 'blocked' column. I've an interface by which I can block users, which sets the block column value to 1. Now, when the user logs in, which is automatically done in Symfony2 by checking the username and password, I redirect them to a controller which checks if the user is blocked from the database and sets error message in a session. 
Then I'm redirecting to logout function which logs the user out and redirects to login page. Now, the problem is, the session is destroyed when the user is logged out and hence I can't inform the user that he has been blocked.

Any suggestions as to how it can be implemented in a better way?

Comment: You should check that before login

Comment: I understand but I need to access the user object to check if the user is blocked or not.

Comment: if username for every user is unique, 
you can check if user blocked or not when user insert username and password in login to Symfony2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony provides the [AdvancedUserInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/AdvancedUserInterface.html) for this functionality. It provides several additional methods like:

```
public Boolean isAccountNonLocked()
public Boolean isEnabled()
```

These methods will be called (on your User entity obviously) before the login. If for example `isEnabled` returns false, the user won't be able to login. You could use those to implement your blocked users.

Comment: I knew about these but wasn't sure about it's usage. I'll certainly implement these in-built methods in future. Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: As per your suggestion, I got isAccountNonLocked() function to use isblocked() to return true or false depending on whether the user is blocked or not. My code is a lot cleaner now. Thanks again for your help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if the user is blocked on login. If the user is blocked the login fails with a "your are blocked" messages.

If you block a logged in user you have to refresh the users session. He would be logged out automatically when refreshing the page.

[**FosUserBundle**](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) has features developing such a behaviour.

Comment: That's the least of my worries at the moment. I just want to prevent the next login. Also, I'm not inclined to use FOS bundles for this.

Comment: You should not inform the user that he was blocked on logout, but on login! You can however redirect the user not to /login but /blocked route when you log him out manually

Comment: I ain't doing that if you read my problem description. Redirecting to login page or any other page for that matter isn't an issue. The problem is maintaining the session message after invalidating the logged in credentials.

Comment: @steady_daddy maintaining the session is not possible out of the box because the session gets invalidated on logout. However you could override symfony2 logout action and copy the message to a new session.

Comment: It worked for the time being but I certainly have to redo it more gracefully. Thanks for your time. Appreciate it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

All right so I'm finally able to do what I wanted to do.
Taking inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6474975/888278), I managed to invalidate the user credentials, session and then place an error message before redirecting.