# How to create a command console that will expire/destroy a session in Symfony2?

Tags: session, symfony, destroy

Guys i want to create a command console that will expire a session or destroy the session in Symfony 2? here's my initial code and its not working :( thanks hope you can help me

```
public function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('pat:session:delete')
            ->setDescription('Delete a existing session')
            ->addArgument('session_id', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'The ID of session that will destroy')
        ;
    }

    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $sessionId = $input->getArgument('session_id');

        $sessionQuery = SessionQuery::create()
            ->filterById($sessionId)->findOne()->toArray();

        $session = $this->getContainer()->get('session');

        //Option 1
        $session->migrate($destroy = false, $lifetime = null);

        //Option 2
        $session->invalidate();

        //Option 3 
        $session->getMetadataBag()->stampNew(1);

        //Option 4
        $session->remove($sessionQuery["Id"]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

// logout Via controller ( Symfony 2.6+ )

$this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken(null);
$this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();

[more info...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464754/symfony2-how-to-log-user-out-manually-in-controller)