# Log user out in Symfony 2 application when "remember me" is enabled

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication, logout

I'm looking for a way to log user out of Symfony 2 application, but could not find a way to do it properly.

I've tried an approach described here:
[Symfony2: how to log user out manually in controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464754/symfony2-how-to-log-user-out-manually-in-controller)

```
$this->get('security.context')->setToken(null);
$this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();
```

It's working fine when "[remember me](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html)" is disabled, however, when I enable it, it's not working. It looks like user is automatically re-authenticated back again by this cookie.

```
remember_me:
    key:      "%secret%"
    lifetime: 31536000
    path:     /
    domain:   ~
    always_remember_me: true
```

What is the proper way to log user out of Symfony 2 application? Do I need to additionally delete this cookie from server-side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have to call the session-storage's `save()` ([Documentation](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/SessionStorageInterface.html#method_save)) method explicitly.

> Force the session to be saved and closed.

Further you can request to delete the **session**- and/or **remember_me**-cookies via response headers.

The **session**-cookie's name is configured as the container-parameter `framework.session.name` and defaults to the `session.name` value from your **php.ini**.

```
$cookieName = $this->container->getParameter('framework.session.name');
$response->headers->clearCookie( $cookieName );
```

The **remember_me**-cookie's name can be configured in your `security` configuration.

```
security:
    firewalls:
        your_firewall:
            remember_me: 
                name: neverforget # <- cookie-name
```

Comment: Did you clear your cache? Please clear your browser cache/cookies and symfony's cache - should be working. Otherwise what's your `ini_get('session.name');` setting?

Comment: The manual removal of cookies helped to resolve the issue, thank you!

Comment: I'm just curious, is it possible to delegate this to Symfony? I think that will be a much better approach.

Comment: What do you mean by delegating this to symfony? ... creating a response-listener that performs the logout if certain conditions are met ?

Comment: No, I mean, Symfony already implements the functionality of logging user out and killing cookies. There is a `LogoutListener` who delegates those action to couple of logout handlers: `CookieClearingLogoutHandler` and `SessionLogoutHandler`. I think the best course of action would be to call those handlers and not to implement such low-level logic ourselves.

Comment: Okay got it. I could provide an example ... but this question's scope was how to do it explicitly based on your code-snippet. Please open a new question for that. Something like ... *How to use the LogoutListener in symfony2* ?

Comment: I was going to do exactly that = )
Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828420/how-to-log-user-out-of-symfony-2-application-using-its-internal-handlers

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to [@nifr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832745/nifr) I was able to resolve this issue. Here's the bulletproof step-by-step guide to log user out of Symfony 2 application manually.

#### Warning

Symfony already implements the functionality of logging user out and deleting cookies. There is a `LogoutListener` who delegates those action to couple of logout handlers: `CookieClearingLogoutHandler` and `SessionLogoutHandler`. I think the best course of action would be to call those handlers and not to implement such low-level logic yourself. However, I can't find a way to do this.

#### Solution

This solution is for Symfony 2.6. The difference is in `security.token_storage`.

1. Add two additional parameters to store cookie names for «session» and «remember me» to your `parameters.yml`:

```
# parameters.yml

parameters:
    session.name: SESS
    session.remember_me.name: LONGSESS
```

2. Update your `config.yml` to use the first parameter for session name:

```
# config.yml

framework:
    session:
        name: "%session.name%"
```

3. Update your `security.yml` to use the second parameter for remember me session name:

```
# security.yml

security:
    firewalls:
        demo_secured_area:
            remember_me:
                name: "%session.remember_me.name%"
```

4. Here's the code you can use to log current user out:

You can use such code inside of a kernel event listener, if you want so.

```php
// SomeController.php

/**
 * @Route("/terminate", name="app.terminate")
 */
public function terminateAction()
{
    // Logging user out.
    $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken(null);

    // Invalidating the session.
    $session = $this->get('request')->getSession();
    $session->invalidate();

    // Redirecting user to login page in the end.
    $response = $this->redirectToRoute('app.login');

    // Clearing the cookies.
    $cookieNames = [
        $this->container->getParameter('session.name'),
        $this->container->getParameter('session.remember_me.name'),
    ];
    foreach ($cookieNames as $cookieName) {
        $response->headers->clearCookie($cookieName);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Here's the implementation of kernel event listener which will force users to log out basing on entity property: [Logging user out of Symfony 2 application using kernel event listener](https://gist.github.com/slavafomin/4e0b70a39d1cff23af0f).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Note that if you use `domain` settings in `session` config, you have to set this value as third argument in `clearCookie`.

Comment: You should use `$response->send();` after clearing the cookies for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

@Slava Fomin II

> Symfony already implements the functionality of logging user out and deleting cookies. There is a LogoutListener who delegates those action to couple of logout handlers: CookieClearingLogoutHandler and SessionLogoutHandler. I think the best course of action would be to call those handlers and not to implement such low-level logic yourself. However, I can't find a way to do this.

Why not simply create a service that calls those?

I looked into `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\LogoutListener` and tested that he calls 2 services during logout (Symfony 3.2.9).

`$tokenBasedRememberMeServices` by the way deletes the remember-me cookie.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyProject\Security\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\DefaultLogoutSuccessHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\SessionLogoutHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\TokenBasedRememberMeServices;

final class LogoutListener
{
    private $sessionLogoutHandler;
    private $tokenBasedRememberMeServices;
    private $defaultLogoutSuccessHandler;
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(
        SessionLogoutHandler $sessionLogoutHandler,
        TokenBasedRememberMeServices $tokenBasedRememberMeServices,
        DefaultLogoutSuccessHandler $defaultLogoutSuccessHandler,
        TokenStorage $tokenStorage
    )
    {
        $this->sessionLogoutHandler = $sessionLogoutHandler;
        $this->tokenBasedRememberMeServices = $tokenBasedRememberMeServices;
        $this->defaultLogoutSuccessHandler = $defaultLogoutSuccessHandler;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function logout(Request $request): void
    {
        $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();
        $response = $this->defaultLogoutSuccessHandler->onLogoutSuccess($request);
        $this->sessionLogoutHandler->logout($request, $response, $token);
        $this->tokenBasedRememberMeServices->logout($request, $response, $token);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. However, this question was asked a long time ago, probably (at least I hope so) Symfony improved it's authentication handling architecture in newer versions. I'm not using Symfony at the moment cause I've switched to Node.js, so I can't be able to verify your answer. Sorry for that! But I hope it will help someone.

Comment: For Symfony `3.2.9` i did not found any provided solution. Hope i help someone with my solution.

Comment: my first question is, is this solution is still good for Symfony 4? Secondly, any specific reasons to use Listener/Subscriber? Why not just use regular service, inject it in Controller and call its logout method there.