# How to log user out of Symfony 2 application using it's internal handlers

Tags: php, security, symfony, logout

Symfony implements the functionality of logging user out and killing cookies. There is a `LogoutListener` which delegates those action to couple of logout handlers: `CookieClearingLogoutHandler` and `SessionLogoutHandler`.

If we want to log user out of application manually, I think the best course of action would be to call those handlers and not to implement (duplicate) such low-level logic yourself.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement an extended logout-listener by overriding the default `security.logout_listener` service.

The default `LogoutListener::requiresLogin(...)` method only checks if the request-path equals a firewall's `logout_path` setting.

It looks like this:

```
protected function requiresLogout(Request $request)
{
    return $this->httpUtils->checkRequestPath(
        $request, $this->options['logout_path']
    );
}
```

---

Now let's assume you want to perform a logout if the session-parameter `logout` is set to `true`.

Therefore we extend the `LogoutListener` class and add our custom `requiresLogout()` method with additional logic.

```
namespace Your\Name\Space;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\LogoutListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

class MyLogoutListener extends LogoutListener {

    /**
     * Whether this request is asking for logout.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Boolean
     */ 
    protected function requiresLogout(Request $request)
    {
        if ( $request->getSession()->get('logout') ) {
            return true;
        }

        return parent::requiresLogout($request);
    }
```

Afterwards we simply override the`security.logout_listener.class` container-parameter with our custom class in our **`config.yml`** .

```
parameters:
    security.logout_listener.class: \Your\Name\Space\MyLogoutListener
```

Now you can logout a user inside a `...Controller` like this:

```
 public function someAction(Request $request) { 

     // ... some logic here

     if ($condition) {      
         $request->getSession()->set('logout', true);
     }
 }
```

Comment: A very elegant solution! Thank you, I will give it a try.

Comment: I didn't have the time to test but it should definitely work like this. Was this what you expected an answer to the question to be like ?

Comment: I have a property in my user entity that states if specific user needs to be kicked out. I can query it like this: `$user->isForceLogout()`. However, is it possible to get the current user inside of this listener? I've tried `$request->getUser()`, but seems like it always returns `NULL`. Also, is it possible to inject some additional service to this listener via a setter? Or the better approach would be to use some other listener to set session variable first?

Comment: I think I will just override the entire service definition with my own and inject required services. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hmm, for some reason I can't get to current user until firewall kernel event listener is finished and I need the user inside of the logout listener in order to decide whether I need to log him out or not. Is it possible to do something about this?

Comment: I've tried to implement the nifr road but I am facing some errors. May be some of you could give me some right hints here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30700770/error-with-base-logout-after-extending-logoutlistener-class

Comment: Is there an alternative for Symfony 3/4?