# error with base logout after extending LogoutListener class

Tags: php, symfony

My target is to perform a logout from a controller being able to have base logout mechanism correctly performing.
After googling and stack-overflowing on some similar  questions I have tried to implement an extension of class LogoutListener as suggested in the answer here [How to log user out of Symfony 2 application using it's internal handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828420/how-to-log-user-out-of-symfony-2-application-using-its-internal-handlers)
I have created the class and I've added the parameter "security.logout_listener.class" in parameters.yml which is imported from config.yml.

Exactly my new class is

```
# MyBundle/MyLogoutListener.php

    namespace MyBundle;

    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\LogoutListener;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

    class MyLogoutListener extends LogoutListener{

        /**
         * Whether this request is asking for logout.
         *
         * @param Request $request
         *
         * @return Boolean
         */ 
        protected function requiresLogout(Request $request)
        {
            if ($request->hasSession())
              if ( $request->getSession->get('logout') ) {
                  return true;
              }
            }

            return parent::requiresLogout($request);
        }
    }
```

And the row I've added in parameters.yml is

```
security.logout_listener.class: MyBundle\MyLogoutListener
```

Whit this things I have a well working logout functionality activable in the login of a controller but if I try to use the base logout functionality of Symfony2  I receive this error :

> Runtime Notice: Declaration of
>   MyBundle\MyLogoutListener::requiresLogout() should be compatible with
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\LogoutListener::requiresLogout(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
>   $request)

For base logout functionality I mean the configuration in the firewall with :

```
…
           logout:
             path:  /logout
             target: /someaction

…
```

Please can somebody explain where is the problem ?
Do I need to define a service with MyLogoutListener ?

Comment: Your `$request` object is currently trying to be injected from the same namespace as your class is - that is `MyBundle`. Add `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` statement at your top as well.

Comment: I've added the use of Request , I've also added a check if $request has session but now I receive this error: "Notice: Undefined property: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::$getSession"

Comment: `$request->getSession->` means you're looking for property, like `public $session`. But in this case, `getSession` is a method, you're missing your braces. Chage it to `$request->getSession()->`

Comment: Ok the braces were the error. Thanks Artamiel , if you post your hint as an answer I'll sign it as the correct answer.