# Symfony 2 does not delete remember-me cookie when logout

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

My goal is to do programmatically logout from controller. I use [this nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28828377/2717270). Everything works fine except that `LONGSESS` (renamed `REMEMBERME`) cookie not deleted. It deleted but not :)

Logout in controller code:

```
$response = $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
$response->headers->clearCookie('LONGSESS');
return $response;
```

So, call this action.

1. Request headers for this action (as expected):

   ```
   Cookie SESS=n4jbl1m61l6bceesbeusrbq044; LONGSESS=QXBwQnVuZGxlXEVudGl0eVxVc2VyOmRYTmxja0IxYzJWeUxtTnZiUT09OjE0NDgyMDMyMjQ6ZTFhNzBlNGEyMWM4NGM3N2UzYmI3ZmJiNWIzMGM5MDg2ZDAyOWY1ZGVhMWI4NTYyNGQ0OTJmNjVmNmRjOTY2NQ%3D%3D
   ```
2. Response headers to this action (as expected):

   ```
   Set-Cookie:SESS=ai1gt79r49o184du3tknv7tdf6; path=/; domain=.myhost.local
   Set-Cookie:LONGSESS=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; httponly
   Set-Cookie:SESS=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; httponly
   ```
3. Redirect headers (as expected):

   ```
   Location:/app_dev.php/
   ```
4. Next request headers to homepage (NOT as expected - `LONGSESS` value is the same as previous request):

   ```
   Cookie:LONGSESS=QXBwQnVuZGxlXEVudGl0eVxVc2VyOmRYTmxja0IxYzJWeUxtTnZiUT09OjE0NDgyMDMyMjQ6ZTFhNzBlNGEyMWM4NGM3N2UzYmI3ZmJiNWIzMGM5MDg2ZDAyOWY1ZGVhMWI4NTYyNGQ0OTJmNjVmNmRjOTY2NQ%3D%3D; SESS=ai1gt79r49o184du3tknv7tdf6
   ```

So user is not logged out.

How may it be? `LONGSESS` cookie set to `deleted`, expired but next request has the same value?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to set third argument `domain` in `clearCookie` method call. It have to be equals to domain in session settings:

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_domain: YOUR-DOMAIN.COM
```

and

```
firewalls:
    your_firewall:
            remember_me:
                domain: YOUR-DOMAIN.COM
```

So, the right way:

```
$response->headers->clearCookie('LONGSESS', '/', 'YOUR-DOMAIN.COM');
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
$response->sendHeaders();
```

right after:

```
$response->headers->clearCookie('LONGSESS');
```

?