# Symfony 4 - Good practice to remove your own user account while connected

Tags: symfony, session, logout, symfony4

I would like my users to be able to delete their own user account. I made a `SecurityController` where there is my 3 functions `login`, `logout` and `deleteUser`. When I delete the current user in database this error appears :

> You cannot refresh a user from the EntityUserProvider that does not contain an identifier. The user object has to be serialized with its own identifier mapped by Doctrine.

When I delete another user, it works correctly because he's not connected.
Do I have to serialize the User and pass it through a Service, logout the user then remove it in a Service? Or can I clear the PHP session in the controller but I don't know how to do it with [symfony4](/questions/tagged/symfony4) I think it changed since version 4.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\UserType;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * @Route("/createAdmin", name="create_admin")
   */
    public function createAdminUser(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
      $usersRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);
      $uCount = $usersRepo->countAllUsers();

      if ($uCount == 0)
      {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user, array(
          'is_fresh_install' => true,
        ));

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            // Encode the password
            $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
            $user->setPassword($password);

            // save the User
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            // Do what you want here before redirecting the user

            return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
        }

        return $this->render('security/register_admin_user.html.twig', array(
          'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
      } else {
        if ($this->getUser())
        {
          return $this->redirectToRoute('user_account');
        } else {
          return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
        }
      }
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authUtils)
    {
      $usersRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);
      $uCount = $usersRepo->countAllUsers();

      if ($uCount == 0)
      {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('create_admin');
      } else {
        $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUsername = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', array(
         'last_username' => $lastUsername,
         'error'         => $error,
        ));
      }
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/delete_user/{id}", name="delete_user")
     */
    public function deleteUser($id)
    {
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $usrRepo = $em->getRepository(User::class);

      $user = $usrRepo->find($id);
      $em->remove($user);
      $em->flush();

      return $this->redirectToRoute('user_registration');

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to logout the user first before deleting the account ?  Sounds like you corrupt your current session if doing so

Comment: Yes, but i have to redirect the user to the login page so in the controller i do : return $this->redirectToRoute('logout'); so the user session is cleared automatically by symfony internal functions. I can't do anything after the logout.

Comment: consider this answer then https://stackoverflow.com/a/28828377/2538899

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SOLUTION :**

You have to clear the Session before deleting user entry in DB with this method:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

// In your deleteUser function...

      $currentUserId = $this->getUser()->getId();
      if ($currentUserId == $id)
      {
        $session = $this->get('session');
        $session = new Session();
        $session->invalidate();
      }
```

I don't know why `$this->get('session')->invalidate();` doesn't work directly... if someone knows :)

Answer (score 1):

I find it also a good solution to do this what is an accepted answer but you can also simply redirect the user to the logout route. 
This has worked for me without any problem in Symfony 4.4

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to serialize the User and pass it through a service.Just check with the previous versions,you will find out the problem.

Comment: Nope, I don't know why we have to serialize it before deleting it. Symfony reloads the user from the DB at every page reloads. The session is updated too. That's why we have to clear the session before redirecting the user to another page.