# How to log a user out properly in the controller?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem to log a user out in the controller properly. I use Symfony 2.4
I did this

```
 $this->get('security.context')->setToken(NULL);
 $this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();
```

and it does not work at all. This code redirected me to the homepage but I am still the logged in user. I tried 5 times and it worked only once. Once I was redirected to login page then to homepage. I did not find in the symfony documentation anything.

I tried this to - no success

```
 $this->get('security.context')->setToken(NULL);
    $this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();

    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->clearCookie('REMEMBERME');

    return $this->render(
                '...index.html.twig',
                array(
                   ...
                ), $response);
```

I am still the logged in user.
So, I only want to log the user out without redirection. 
 Why cannot symfony do such a basic thing.

**EDIT:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/22223566/2241432
My problem is: I must stay at the same controller. I must not redirect to /logout route, I must not return the empty Response.  I have many registrations in the app, so the yml configuration cannot solve my problem. For each registration I need different solution. I only want to destroy user and show the proper twig (never homepage).
I need this solution

```
   $this->get('security.context')->setToken(NULL);
    $this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();

    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->clearCookie('REMEMBERME');

    return $this->render(
                '...index.html.twig',
                array(
                   ...
                ), $response);
```

Can someone explain why this does not work? How to log the user out and show proper layout in different controllers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2: how to log user out manually in controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464754/symfony2-how-to-log-user-out-manually-in-controller)

Comment: This helps
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29388369/2241432