# Symfony2 FOSUSerBundle boost multiaccount users

Tags: security, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to create a hunter of multiple accounts to prevent a user with an IP can create multiple accounts in my application.

I created a login event listener of FOSUserBunde, here is the function.

```
class FOSUserLoginListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $em;
    private $userManager;
    private $router;
    private $requestStack;
    private $mailer;
    private $templating;

public function __construct(UserManager $usermanager, Router $router, RequestStack $requestStack, TwigEngine $templating, EntityManager $em, $mailer)
{
    $this->em                   = $em;
    $this->userManager          = $usermanager;
    $this->router               = $router;
    $this->requestStack         = $requestStack;
    $this->mailer               = $mailer;
    $this->templating           = $templating;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN => 'onImplicitLogin',
        SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onSecurityInteractiveLogin',
    );
}
public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
{
    $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

    if ($user instanceof UserInterface) {
        $lastIp = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getClientIp();
        if($this->multiAccountChecker($lastIp))
        {
            $this->sendAlertToBanEmail($user, $lastIp);
            $user->setLastIP($lastIp)
                 ->setLocked(true);
            $this->userManager->updateUser($user);                
            $this->userManager->reloadUser($user);
        }
        $user->setLastIP($lastIp);
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }
}
```

It works fine except for one little glitch. When I detect more than one account with the same IP, data is stored in the database but the user being logged will not close the session with the message "This account is locked."

Someone could give me some clue as to ensure that, in case of a multiple account the user is refused access?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions

```
$this->userManager->updateUser($user);                
$this->userManager->reloadUser($user);
```

just save the user's data into the DB and then refresh the in-memory user.

You should do a programmatic logout for the current user; see the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6474975/5192753.