# Remove authenticated user from context Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to know the instruction how to remove a user that has just been authenticated so it would be like no user has been authenticated.

Should I delete the content of the session or is there a proper way ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Basically you want to log out a user as soon as he has logged in?

Comment: In case of a success authentication : if the password is more than 3 months, I force to change it but i want the user not to be authenticated doing so. He will have to relog with the new password

Comment: It must be tricky to change password for not authenticated user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this :

```
$this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken(null);
$this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if the password is older than 3 months, you need to force the user to the `change password` site. He shouldn't be able to do something else but to change the password, as long as he doesn't change it.

You must not break the authentication, because the user never could change the password if he isn't authenticated.

After the user changes his password you could log him out and redirect him back to home or the login page.

To log a user out of your system you need to invalidate his Token and Session.
You'll find more information to the manually logout of an user in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464754/symfony2-how-to-log-user-out-manually-in-controller).

```
// manual logout 
$this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken(null);
$this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();
```

So this code would be placed in the `$form->isValid()` part of the password change form.

Comment: I understand what you say, but in my case he can do it and I want a relog in