# Symfony identify user with email link

Tags: php, symfony

I am not sure if I this question is clear. So I will just try to explain what I am trying to achieve. Let's say user has 2 accounts on a website. He is logged in to one account. But receives email notification with link to page for another account. When he clicks to the link, how to logout him from another account and ask to login to correct one?

I am using [jwt bundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle) for user authentication

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not sure, but you have frontend app with symfony backend (because of jwt)? if you write regular app you able to check on referred to link-route action that user has access , e.g. by some link parameter which identifies user, and if is incorrect then logout and force login form.
Ways how to logout user you can find in related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464754/symfony2-how-to-log-user-out-manually-in-controller)

Best regards