# FosUserBundle impersonating externally

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, impersonation

I am trying to impersonate via an external link. For example `https://example.com/?_switch_user=email`. So when clicking on a button it will redirect the user and impersonate immediately. That works fine. The issue is when i try to impersonate a new user, it results to a 500 error. As expected because there is a impersonation active. My question is: is it possible to first run `https://example.com/?_switch_user=_exit` on the background and then redirect to the new user externally.

This is my code so far:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/client/{email}", name="client-impersonate")
 */
public function impersonate($email)
{
    // first run someting to exit the active impersonation and then redirect below

    return $this->redirect('https://example.com/?_switch_user='.$email);
}
```

My backup solution would be to create some kind of listener on `example.com` to first check if there is an active impersonation and "exit" that first.
But i was wondering if i can do it also with the code above. (before redirecting)

Comment: Not sure what "impersonating" means but if it means logged in then logging out from code before redirection should do the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464754/symfony2-how-to-log-user-out-manually-in-controller

Comment: Before I can get my hand onto the Symfony code, my best guess is to check what `switch_user` endpoint  with `_exit` does and do the same thing in your controller.